# How to reduce the xlsx size after webpack

Tags: js-xlsx

In my angular 5 application, I use xlsx to read content (contact information of teacher like email and name) from microsoft excel file, after webpack the  application for production, I found the size of xlsx module is as large as 1.1M compared to all @angular module size as 1.6M, is there some method to reduce the size considering only use parsing function?

===========================
updated:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "xlsx": "^0.12.10",
  ...
},
```

in ts file:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
```

then use XLSX.WorkBook and WorkSheet and XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json, etc.

Comment: Which xlsx module are we talking about? How are you using and importing it? Please add some code.

Comment: in package.json file, inside dependencies section: "xlsx": "^0.12.10"

Comment: @AKX please see my update in original post, in stats.tml, there are 3 parts: xlsx.js, jszip.js and dist.

Comment: Okay. Well, since xlsx is distributed as a single bundled file, there's nothing Webpack can do to remove dead code in it :(

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tried https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/694#issuecomment-468745153

const xlsx = await import('xlsx');

It only loads the xlsx.js when you use need xlsx. It will not reduce the bundle size but splits the code which will be loaded only when you use it.